# Auto login and repository configuration in eclipse for git

Tags: git, github, egit

I have configured `eclipse` with `Git` and able to do a `commit` and `push`, but every time I have to do a `push`, I need to provide the `repository information`.

This seems to be a bit of overwork and unnecessary repetition. Is there a way to do it as a one-time set up?

I explored the `remote` option in the `Repository View`.
Do I need to `create a new remote` and point to my existing repository in `Github`?

What other configurations I need to provide?

Comment: I haven't use eclipse with git, but probably yes, you should create a new remote as `remote` is how `git` names non-local repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse myself, so I don't know Eclipse / EGit specific bits.  In commandline Git the command [`git remote add`](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote) can be used to add an information about repository and give said repository short name.  You can then just use the name of said repository e.g. in `git push remote-repo` or `git push remote-repo feature-branch` (to push a branch for a very first time).

You can also configure repository to be default, or default for pushing, so you can use `git fetch` or `git push`.

All information about repositories is saved in human readable form in [git config file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) ('`.git/config`'); you can view and edit it there.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually it turned out to be pretty simple 2 step process. Create a new Remote, configure fetch and push. Configuration is all about specifying local and remote repositories to be synced up. This is all we need to do.